# NVIDIA card and Bumblebee refuse to run

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Whenever I try to use `optirun` to run a program using my NVIDIA card, I get this error message:

```
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/<user>/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/<user>/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Programs like `glxgears` return a blank screen and some games refuse to run at all. Everything is properly set in my Bumblebee config, but for some reason the system refuses to load the proper version of LibGL. How can I fix this?

---

Output of `ldconfig -p | grep libGL`:

```
libGLU.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
libGLU.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
libGLEWmx.so.1.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEWmx.so.1.10
libGLEW.so.1.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10
libGLESv2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGLESv2.so.2
libGLESv2.so.2 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGLESv2.so.2
libGLESv2.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGLESv2.so
libGLESv2.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGLESv2.so
libGLESv1_CM.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
libGLESv1_CM.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
libGLESv1_CM.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGLESv1_CM.so
libGLESv1_CM.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGLESv1_CM.so
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so
libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.so
```

[Trimmed] output of `inxi -F`:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GT 745M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.1 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: intel)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.1hz, 1680x1050@59.9hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GT 745M/PCIe/SSE2
           GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 352.21
```

I am currently running NVIDIA Driver 352.21, installed from the xorg-edgers ppa.